# Using OUTPUT INTO clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am using `OUTPUT INTO` to clause to insert certain columns into table `dbo.Cache` from a temporary table `#Temp2`.  Values are inserted in `#Temp2` via a `select` statement.

I want grouped data to be inserted only in `dbo.Cache` and not in `#Temp2`.This is my query so far but Group By is certainly at the wrong place. Also, I realise that aggregates are not allowed in `OUTPUT` clause. I get syntax error at it. Is there a work around for this, please ?

```
INSERT INTO #Temp2 (RowNumber, ValFromUser, ColumnName, ValFromFunc, FuncWeight, percentage)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ValFromUser, INSERTED.ColumnName, INSERTED.RowNumber, MAX(INSERTED.ValFromFunc)
INTO dbo.CACHE (StringSearched, ColName, RowId, PercentMatch)
GROUP BY Inserted.ValFromUser, Inserted.ColumnName, Inserted.RowNumber 
   SELECT 
      RowNumber, @firstname, 'firstname', PercentMatch, @constVal, PercentMatch * @constVal 
   FROM   
      dbo.MatchFirstName(@firstname)
```

Comment: You're asking every single step you're doing here with a separate question? Maybe you should try at least few hours to do it yourself first?

Comment: And a hint, can't you just insert the data into the next place from the temp table you just filled?

Comment: Okay. I understand. Had tried using Group by in different ways in the query but as a matter of fact it is that aggregate functions are not allowed in Output clause, I had doubt if this at all is possible to use a group by clause here and hence posted to know.

Comment: No, you cannot group the results of an output clause, it's just an output

Comment: Thank you . I got your hint but I want only and only those rows to be inserted in dbo.Cache which were inserted in #Temp2 in very last step. While doing insert for second time in dbo.Cache from dbo.Insert, I would not want already inserted values to be inserted again in dbo.Cache. Shall I consider checking the rows that have already been inserted in Cache and then insert rest of the rows from #Temp2 into dbo.Cache ?

Comment: You can figure out that by testing it, right?

Comment: okay :) I will just do and post back here if it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do that in two different insert statements

First insert into `#temp2` table

```
INSERT INTO #temp2 
            (rownumber, 
             valfromuser, 
             columnname, 
             valfromfunc, 
             funcweight, 
             percentage) 
SELECT rownumber, 
       @firstname, 
       'firstname', 
       percentmatch, 
       @constVal, 
       percentmatch * @constVal 
FROM   dbo.Matchfirstname(@firstname)
```

Then insert the grouped result from `#temp2` table into `dbo.cache` table

```
INSERT INTO dbo.cache 
            (stringsearched, 
             colname, 
             rowid, 
             percentmatch) 
SELECT valfromuser, 
       columnname, 
       rownumber, 
       Max(valfromfunc) 
FROM   #temp2  
GROUP  BY valfromuser, 
          columnname, 
          rownumber
```

Comment: Statements of the type are repeated in my procedure. Calling the inline TVF twice everytime probably will be bad for performance , isn't it ?

Comment: Your requirement cannot be done in a single insert statement. There is nothing wrong in calling a function twice. If your function has some complex logic then insert the result of function into temp table then use the temp table here .

Comment: @Simran - AS per **Jamez** comment you can use the previous temp table to do the second insert instead of calling the function again. Updated my answer

Comment: I want only and only those rows to be inserted in dbo.Cache which were inserted in #Temp2 in very last step. While doing insert for second time in dbo.Cache from dbo.Insert, I would not want already inserted values to be inserted again in dbo.Cache. Shall I consider checking the rows that have already been inserted in Cache and then insert rest of the rows from #Temp2 into dbo.Cache ?